# How do I round a float number to a certain number of digits, in a portable way

Tags: floating-point, common-lisp, rounding

Most of the time when someone asks how to round a float to a certain number of digits, the classic answer given is to use FORMAT :

```
(format nil "~,2F" 6.376)
==> "6.38"
```

However, in a particular case, the rounding using FORMAT is **implementation dependant !**

In [CLHS - 22.3.3.1 Tilde F: Fixed-Format Floating-Point](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cca.htm) :

> When rounding up and rounding down would produce printed values
> equidistant from the scaled value of arg, then the implementation is
> free to use either one. For example, printing the argument 6.375 using
> the format ~4,2F may correctly produce either 6.37 or 6.38.

Moreover, `ffloor` does not seem to me to allow rounding to several digits after the decimal point.

So my question is : How do you explicitly round the number 6.375 to 6.37 **in a portable way** ?

Comment: see: ffloor, fceiling, ftruncate

Comment: How do you round 6.375 to 6.37 with ffloor ? It does seem to allow that kind of rounding, or maybe you could do this horrible thing : (/ (ffloor (* 6.375 100)) 100)

Comment: @JérômeRadix Tips: avoid any `+ 0.5` approach as that fails corner cases.  First test if value has a fraction, then scaling by 100, round, divide by 100.  Test needed to not overflow.

Comment: Note that `6.xx5` might not encoded using decimal encoding and so `x.xx5` may encode as a number like `x.xx499999....` or `x.xx5000000....5`.  Thus since the values is not exactly half-way between `x.xx000` and `x.xx0000 + 0.01`, the rounded value is not in the direction expected.  For details, print your value out to at least 17 significant decimal places.

Comment: Jérôme Radix, "How do you explicitly round the number 6.375 to 6.37 in a portable way ?" is curious.  Why do you want the half-way case to round down?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica wanting to round to 6.38 is the same problem as you can't use FORMAT for that purpose too as it is implementation dependant (see question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the answer is to use numerical functions, not I/O ones.

The obvious (indeed, pretty much the only) way to do this is by multiplying the number by 10^n, then rounding to integer and then dividing by 10^n.  In CL the [various rounding functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm) are specified in a way which makes this a little easier:

```
(defun fround-to-n-digits (v &optional (n 0))
  ;; These declarations are really to show intent: FLOAT is not enough
  ;; to optimize although perhaps a good type-inferencing compiler can
  ;; work out that this takes double->double &c.
  (declare (type float v)
           (type (integer 0) n))
  (let ((10^-n (expt 10 (- n))))
    (* (fround v 10^-n)
       10^-n)))
```

`round` and `fround` are defined to round to even in the usual way, `truncate` rounds towards zero, `floor` rounds down, `ceiling` rounds up.

However **note** that this will certainly run into float-representation issues the moment you look at it even slightly hard: such is the way with any floating-point maths.  In particular if you assume that `(fround-to-n-digits x 2)` will always print some nice thing with two decimal digits you're in for an unpleasant surprise.

Comment: Do you think a test about the magnitude of `v` before scaling it is needed to prevent overflow?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes, but in the cases where you might get overflow you probably are not going to be caring about rounding to 2 decimal places (in fact the function is misnamed, it should be round-to-n-decimal-places or something).  In general I find it hard to think of a use for this function at all so I didn't spend much time on it.